# Обновление значений в двух таблицах при равенстве

Tags: sql, sqlite

Имеется две таблицы:

Таблица А: `number, inn, sum, status`

Таблица B: `inn, sum, number`

Требуется сравнить значения inn и sum на равенство в обеих таблицах (`A.inn=B.inn and A.sum=B.sum`)

Если я ничего не напутал, то запрос будет таким:

`select A.inn, A.sum, A.number from A LEFT join B on A.inn=B.inn and A.sum=B.sum where B.number is 'not mapped'`

И теперь мне требуется обновить `A.status` на `+` и `B.number` на `A.number` и тут загвоздка, потому как насколько я понял *SQLite doesn't support JOINs in UPDATE statements*.

Как это можно реализовать и возможно ли вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил не обновлять `A.status`:

```
UPDATE B
SET number = (SELECT A.number
      FROM A
      WHERE A.sum = B.sum
       AND A.inn = B.inn)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
     FROM A
     WHERE A.sum = B.sum
     AND A.inn = B.inn)
```