# Выборка из двух таблиц в MySQL по запросу

Tags: mysql

Нужна помощь c MySQL. Есть 2 таблицы

```
spisok (id, name, id_kat);
kat (id, name, rod);
```

где id_kat = id(второй таблицы)
rod - содержит в себе id записи из второй таблицы и показывает id родительской записи этой же таблицы. Если он сам является род. записью, то там rod=0. Чтобы было белее понятно, пример.

```
Таблица spisok 
id name id_kat
1  Вася 1
2  Петя 4
3  Петя 2
4  Петя 3

Таблица kat
id name rod
1  ххх  0
2  yyy  0
3  zzz  1
4  ccc  1
```

1. Нужно сделать выборку из таблицы spisok всех записей у которых rod=1 в таблице kat
2. Нужно сделать выборку из таблицы spisok всех записей у которых rod=1 в таблице kat и id=1
   **Заранее благодарен.**

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142807/234134 вдруг натолкнет на решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте конструкцию LEFT JOIN ON.

1 выборка делается так

```
SELECT * FROM spisok LEFT JOIN kat ON kat.id = spisok.id_kat WHERE kat.rod = 1;
```

естественно вместо * можно возвращать например spisok.name, kat.name для получения более удобочитаемого вывода.

А вот насчет 2 выборки я вообще не понял логики, единственно что пришло на ум, это добавить условие на id из таблицы spisok, так?

```
SELECT * FROM spisok LEFT JOIN kat ON kat.id = spisok.id_kat WHERE kat.rod = 1 AND spisok.id = 1;
```

С точки зрения оптимизации это может не самый правильный запрос, возможно вот этот более правильный, с конструкцией INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM spisok INNER JOIN kat ON kat.rod=1 AND kat.id = spisok.id_kat
```

Comment: Спасибо. Смысл понял. Дальше буду копать сам. Во втором WHERE kat.rod = 1 AND kat.id = 1; должно быть так скорее всего

Comment: Вот смысла этого я и не понял. Как может категория быть родителем самой себе, если у вас такой вариант обозначается rod=0 ?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN kat ... WHERE kat.rod = 1;` Однозначно downvote.

Comment: Уважаемый Akina прокомментировал, да не докомментировал. 
На его основе задумался и возможно действительно не совсем правильно составил запрос.
Есть вот такой вариант с INNER JOIN
SELECT * FROM spisok INNER JOIN kat ON kat.rod=1 AND kat.id = spisok.id_kat

Comment: категория быть родителем самой себе естественно не может. Тут смысл задумывался такой. Если у записи rod=0 то она родительская, если >0 то в rod указывается id родительской записи. Т.е в примере в таблице kat запись "xxx" является родительской для записей "zzz" и "ccc".